# Malformed archive while compiling v8

Tags: v8

I am trying to build an executable file for Ubuntu machine for v8.

The following is the command executed :

```
g++ -g -ggdb -o Engine -lm *.o  -Wl,--start-group /home/atdesk-83/v8/out/native/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -pthread
```

I am receiving the error :

> /home/atdesk-83/v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: error
>   adding symbols: Malformed archive collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: How did you compile V8? The docs at https://v8.dev/docs/embed recommend using the v8_monolith target to simplify things; please try following those steps.

Comment: I used the command :g++ -std=c++0x -g -c -w -ggdb -Wall -fPIC -c -I ./ *.cpp -I/home/atdesk-83/v8/ -D__LINUX__

Comment: That may be how you compiled your stuff, but I asked how you compiled *V8*. Please follow the official instructions.

Comment: The following steps were followed :1.Install Git 2.Install Depot Tools from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git 3.Executed the command : "export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools" 4.Make Directory and fetch v8 Source 5.Executed the above mentioned command - ":g++ -std=c++0x -g -c -w -ggdb -Wall -fPIC -c -I ./ *.cpp -I/home/atdesk-83/v8/ -D__LINUX__ "

Comment: "fetch v8" does not compile anything. You'll have to compile V8 before linking your own app against it. See https://v8.dev/docs/embed#run-the-example.